# How to implement persistent drawer using NG-ZORRO?

Tags: angularjs, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to implement a persistent drawer using [NG-ZORROR drawer](https://ng.ant.design/components/drawer/en).

Currently the NG-ZORROR drawer is only available in overlay mode which is nice for tablets but I would like to have a menu that can push the content when open for desktop.

I would like to end with something like [material-ui drawer](https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer) solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `BreakpointObserver` method provided by the CDK to observe the screen size and then switch between `nz-drawer` and `nz-sider`.

- [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/hsuanxyz/demo-sidenav)
- [Github](https://github.com/hsuanxyz/demo-sidenav)